# Unable to install python3.6 virtualenv in Ubuntu 19.10 ('no module named apport')

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, setuptools

I've upgraded my ubuntu distro to 19.10 and now I can't install virtualenv for python3.6. I can create virtualenv for python3.7 with no issues by typing 'virtualenv NAME --python=python3' but when I replace python3 with python3.6, I get the following output.

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
    import distutils.sysconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apport'
```

Python3.6 runs fine when I type in python3.6 into shell. 
I have python3-pip, python3-setuptools and python3-distutils installed.

Comment: I know this is not an actual fix for your problem but "virtualenv" is actually deprecated and you should use [venv(https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)] instead. `python3 -m venv NAME` should work as a workaround.

Comment: Good point. While using this command, I am:
- able to create a 3.7 env by typing in 'python3.7 -m venv NAME'
- unable to create a 3.6 env by typing in 'python3.6-m venv NAME' (error message below)
- get the same error message when i type in 'python3-m venv NAME'
Message: 
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command. apt-get install python3-venv
[I do have that installed, also python3.6-venv installed.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Ubuntu (fresh), installed python3.7-venv and python3.8-venv, installed python3.6 (manually) and it worked then with the command:

> python3.6 -m venv NAME

Not sure which fixed it. I expected I'd need python3.6-venv but I didn't.